# Call method for each line in a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing a Java application that is supposed to call a method for every line in a file. It then opens a custom dialog box. I am using this code to read the file:

```
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String> ();
        String line = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.ospt"));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                lines.add(line) ;
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(String line1 : lines)
        {
           execute(line1);
         }
```

And this is the execute() method:

```
public static void execute(String script) {
    if (script.contains("tell $DESKTOP -dialog")) {
        String s = txt.getText();
         Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([^)]+)\\]").matcher(s);
         String stuff = null;
         while(m.find()) {
            stuff = m.group(1);
         }
         String[] dialogParts = stuff.split(",");
         String part1 = dialogParts[0].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
         String part2 = dialogParts[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
         String part3 = dialogParts[2].replaceAll("\\s+", "");
         int part3int = Integer.parseInt(part3);

         if (part3int == 0) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Mainframe.instance, part2, part1, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         }

         if (part3int == 1) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Mainframe.instance, part2, part1, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }

         if (part3int == 2) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Mainframe.instance, part2, part1, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
         }

         if (part3int == 3) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Mainframe.instance, part2, part1, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
         }
    }
}
```

Yet after using this for loop to call execute() on each line of the file:

```
for(String line1 : lines)
{
execute(line1);
}
```

It treats 'line1' as the entire file and I get an error as execute cannot read the entire file. Can I feed each line into the execute() method instead of it trying to read the entire file?

Comment: Where are you using `script` inside `execute`?

Comment: Seems to me like a LF vs CR issue... What operating system are you using, and which editor did you use to craft your text file?

Comment: Sorry, code had a mistake in it. txt.getText() needed to be 'script'.

Comment: If this is now fixed, you should probably delete this question so others don't waste time working on it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are putting the lines into a list and then iterating through them. Why not call execute on each line as you read it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title directly ...

If you are using Java 8 then you could replace your iteration with:

```
lines.forEach(MyClass::execute);
```

Or even better you could call it directly from the lines as they are read:

```
Files.lines(Path.get(path)).forEachOrdered(MyClass::execute);
```